# Adding to an array in another class?

Tags: java, javafx

I currently have a Customer class with an ArrayList in it.

This:

```
package sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Customer {
    private String customernumber;
    private ArrayList customerorder;

    public Customer(String customernumber, ArrayList customerorder) {
        this.customernumber = customernumber;
        this.customerorder = customerorder;
    }

    public String getCustomernumber() {
        return customernumber;
    }

    public void setCustomernumber(String customernumber) {
        this.customernumber = customernumber;
    }

    public ArrayList getCustomerorder() {
        return customerorder;
    }

    public void setCustomerorder(ArrayList customerorder) {
        this.customerorder = customerorder;
    }
}
```

In another class i want add all the items in one array and add it to the array in the Customer class.

I've created an instance of it at the top

```
private Customer cus = new Customer();
```

and an order array within the other class.

```
private ObservableList<FoodDrink> order = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Also a button event that should add all the items.

```
public void btnSubmitOrder(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

}
```

I understand I'm supposed to loop it but I'm unsure of how to properly access the array and add all the items in this class' array to the Customer array.

Comment: The code you've posted, specifically `private Customer cus = new Customer();`, won't compile. But assuming what you mean is that you want to add everything in `order` to the list in `Customer`, why can't you just do `cus.getCustomerOrder().addAll(order)`?

Comment: ive tried
public void btnSubmitOrder(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        cus.getCustomerOrder().addAll(order)
    }

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Oh wait seems to work cheers

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0):

Your code will read better if you use plural name for the list. Also, you should be using camelCase in naming your variables and methods.

```
private ArrayList customerOrders ;
```

The answer to your question lies in that getter method you wrote, `getCustomerOrders`. That method returns an `ArrayList`. By the way, it should return the more general `List` if no methods specific to `ArrayList` will be needed.

```
public List< CustomerOrder > getCustomerOrders() {
    return customerOrders;
}
```

Notice how we used angle brackets to denote that out list will contain objects of the type `CustomerOrder`. Do the same to your member variable, `private List< CustomerOrder > customerOrders ;`.

Call that getter method to get a reference to the list object. For example, let’s look up the `Customer` object that represents our customer Alice.

```
Customer aliceCustomer = … ;
List< CustomerOrder > aliceOrders = aliceCustomer.getCustomerOrders() ;
```

Use that reference to add a new order to that collection.

```
aliceOrders.add( new CustomerOrder( … ) ) ;
```

Comment: But also, don't use raw types, don't use `ArrayList` as a compile-time type, etc.